# Cannot add users to On Premise Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I'm using Microsoft On Premise Azure Devops Server for first time, i have created a project and i need to add users to our team on project but i can't and below image show: **No identities found**.

Please i want to know which users can be added and how to add it.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use their active directory identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can add users who are a member of your Azure Active Directory in Project/Team directly*** , the members format will be ***`user@<AzureADprimarydomain> (ex: user@test.onmicrosoft.com)`*** like below:

[image]

But ***to add external users you will have to invite them to your organization first*** and ***then add them in the project/team***. You can go to ***`organization settings >> users >> add new users >> provide the email-id >> add which project the user will be part of and also select the permission level of the user >> add`*** .

[image]

**References:**

- To know more about ***Azure Devops Server 2020*** you can refer this
  ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/devops/server/admin/admin-quick-ref?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)***
- ***[`Add Users to Organization and Manage Access`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#add-users-to-your-organization)***

Comment: Thank you @AnsumanBal-MT this answer saved my day.